# How to put the seed values of K-means algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to group customers according to a certain given dataset with attributes like DOB, Gender, State, pincode, transaction_id, promocode etc.

Every time I run the algorithm there is a huge difference in the silhouette score of the clustering from the previous one i.e. the result is not consistent.
Probably that is because of the random seeds to the datasets. Here is the line which passes attribute to the algorithm.

```
km1 = KMeans(n_clusters=6, n_init=25, max_iter = 600)
```

Is there any method to assign clusters or optimise such that after everytime I run the program, the score is consistent and better?

I am using Python 3 with scikit-learn.

Comment: What language & framework are we talking about here? Is it Python with scikit-learn? Please clarify (specific tagging could also do the job)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks (i'm guessing) like you are using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

In this case, just use:

```
km1 = KMeans(n_clusters=6, n_init=25, max_iter = 600, random_state=MYSEED)
```

where `MYSEED` can be an integer, RandomState object or None (default) as explained in above link.

This means:

```
km1 = KMeans(n_clusters=6, n_init=25, max_iter = 600, random_state=0)
```

is inducing deterministic results.

**Remark:** this only effects k-means random-nature. If you did some splitting / CV to your data, you have to make these operations deterministic too!

Comment: if someone uses `n_init=10` and `random_state = 1234`, then then answer does not make sense. How can you initialize randomly 10 times the centroids having a fixed `random_state` ???

Comment: @serafeim What do you mean? `n_init=x` corresponds to a single-run KMeans run with multiple starts but a single seeding procedure.

Comment: right so multiple starts means multiple initial centroids but how can these centroids be different if the random_state is fixed. I am missing something here

Comment: There are two perspectives to this: 1) You assume there is a seeding for each run (with the same seed). This is basically wrong. You will only seed once for deterministic behaviour. The 2nd run will use the same PRNG, but it's state is already "advanced" due to previous usage. That's something important to understand if someone is new to PRNGs (don't seed too often).2)Technically, there is multiple-seeding. But only due do parallelization and co which will complicate things. For the user it's not important: a constant will be deterministic behaviour, but all inits will be (with high prob) diff

Comment: If you don't trust me, just read the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L389). The PRNG will be initialized with your constant. Then THIS STATE after seeding will be used to get new random-values as new seeds for your runs. This is enough for deterministic behaviour. Again: this complication is just because of the more general code allowing parallelization.

Comment: perfect. that makes sense. so it is safe and correct to define both `n_init` and `random_state` at the same time. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197571/discussion-between-serafeim-and-sascha).

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your `random_state=` to a constant value. But don't tweak this value until you like the results.

If k-means is sensitive to the starting conditions (I.e. the "quality" varies a lot) this usually indicates that the algorithm doesn't work on this data very well. It has been shown that *if* there is a good k-means clustering then it will be easy to get at least *close* to this with most runs. So with `n_init=25` you should find a good solution almost every time, *if* there is one. But there are many data sets where k-means *cannot* find a good solution!

Comment: have a look at my comment of the above answer. any tip?

Comment: What is the question there? If you have doubts about the effect of an option, check the source code of the version that you are using. Behavior can change over time. The source code is what you are using, that is the reliable source to find out what an option does, or how the random seed is used...